# Is there a way to open my last tmux session by typing "tmux" instead of "tmux a"?

Tags: tmux

I would like to open my last tmux session without typing "tmux a". Instead I would like to type only "tmux".

Every time I run "tmux", it opens a new session window.

Comment: Two keystrokes is difficult why?

Comment: @KenWhite I can't speak for OP but personally I use these commands so often that, yes, two more keystrokes *is* annoying. In fact, I use a single-letter function (`t`) to list and/or select tmux sessions, as well as a second alias `t.` to attach to a session based on the current directory name.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is yes, it's doable. That is where alias comes for help.
To achieve that you can create an alias as below.

```
alias tmux="tmux a"
```

**But I won't recommend it**. If you don't have open session and run above, you lose the flexibility to open new session.

Instead I recommend below alias.

```
alias tmux="tmux a || tmux"
```

It tries to join existing tmux session, if no existing session then open a new one.